# Template in GCC doesn't see a function declared after it, but before instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Here is what Visual Studio compiles well:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
T read()
{
    T value;
    read(value); // gcc compile error here
    return value;
}

void read(std::string& str)
{
}

template <typename T>
void read(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    read<std::string>();
    read<std::vector<int>>();
    read<std::vector<float>>();

    return 0;
}
```

But GCC generates compile error: no matching function for call...

I found the only solution which works for me, to declare template function read(T&) before read():

```
template <typename T>
void read(T&);

template <typename T>
T read()
{
    T value;
    read(value);
    return value;
}

template <>
void read(std::string& str)
{
}

//template <typename T>
//void read(std::vector<T>& vec)
//{
//}
```

but I can't figure out how to fit template functions in it.

Is there any better ways to make gcc see functions declared after template which uses them, but before template's instantiation?

Comment: Compile error for which call? If VS compiles it then that's probably its non-standard extension allowing temporaries to bind to non-`const` references, though I can't immediately see why this code would attempt to do that.

Comment: Compile errors are for all calls.

Comment: Your two programs are not equivalent. You did more than just swapping the order of definitions. Please provide an example on Coliru.

Comment: Try to declare this before `main`: `template<typename B> struct X : B { };` and then call `read< X<std::string> >()`, likewise for the vector. But: don't blame me for when your code review fails :D

Comment: Isn't that yet another effect of VS broken two-phase lookup? ADL (performed in the second phase, from the POI) won't find `read` in the first code block..

Comment: @dyp Yep. ADL will not examine the global namespace since the associated namespaces are just std.

Comment: I understand, that VS probably uses some kind of tricks to do that, but I need to make the code portable. So I'm looking for best solution to make that without changing order of these functions (they are in different files and included everywhere in code).

Comment: @GLaz the template implicitly states that `T` shall provide a `read` function in its free-function interface pool. `std::string` has chosen not to do that, because in its namespace apparently no such function exists. Complain either to the author of `read` or to the author of `std::string`. If you are the former, perhaps you can use a trait like `ReadTrait<T>::read(value)` and require the callers of `read` to specialize that trait.

Comment: Accepting an answer is sufficient, don't provide your own answer into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow later overwrites (without forwarding) you may introduce a tag (in the namespace where read is declared) for name look up:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Read {
    template <typename T>
    struct Tag {};

    template <typename T>
    T read()
    {
        T value;
        read(Tag<T>(), value);
        return value;
    }
} // namespace Read

template <typename T>
T read()
{
    return Read::read<T>();
}

namespace Read {
    void read(Tag<std::string>, std::string& str)
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    void read(Tag<std::vector<T>>, std::vector<T>& vec)
    {
    }
} // namespace Read

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    read<std::string>();
    read<std::vector<int>>();
    read<std::vector<float>>();

    return 0;
}
```

(Note: It works in the global namespace, too)

Comment: Since when does declaration order matter?

Comment: Thanks a lot. See the solution based on your thoughts in update.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the order of your declarations well:

```
template <typename T>
T read()
{
    T value;
    read(value); // gcc compile error here
    return value;
}

void read(std::string& str) {}

template <typename T>
void read(std::vector<T>& vec) {}
```

GCC complains because argument-dependent lookup, **the only lookup that can find names declared in the instantiation- but not in the definition context**, does not find the last two overloads of `read`.
This is because

1. The set of associated namespaces of `std::string` (or `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<float>`, respectively) includes `std`, but not the global namespace, which is where your overloads are declared in.
2. The set of associated namespaces of any fundamental type, including `int` or `float`, is empty.

Thus the global namespace is never searched for overloads declared after your template. Such postponed lookup of names in the instantiation context is apparently bugged in VC++, which is why your code compiles with it.

This is solved by declaring the overloads not found by ADL in the definition context, so that they can be found by ordinary unqualified name lookup. I.e.

```
void read(std::string& str);
template <typename T>
void read(std::vector<T>& vec);

template <typename T>
T read()
{
    T value;
    read(value); // gcc compile error here
    return value;
}
```

[Makes your code compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4addff178e17bc19). A definition is clearly also a declaration, so putting the entire definitions there works as well (if the definitions of your latter two overloads do not depend on that function template!).

Comment: The problem is not in std::, because void read(int& i) doesn't compile as well. I also have hundreds of overloads of read(...), so can't make declaration of all of them in the start.

Comment: @GLaz The set of associated namespaces for fundamental types is empty (and therefore does not include the global namespace). Same thing, essentially.

Comment: Thanks. But maybe there is a way to make for vector "templated" specialization (see my second code snapshot and commented out code)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't just swap the order. You changed this:

```
template <typename T>
void read(std::vector<T>& vec)
{}
```

to this:

```
template <typename T>
void read(T&);
```

The two are completely different! It may be that deduction cannot take place in that former case.

Comment: I didn't swap anything. I added template declaration of read(T&) in the start to make read() see all specializations of this declaration after read(). But read(std::vector<T>&) doesn't fit in this solution because it is template, so I commented it out.

Comment: @GLaz: Can you not see that you introduced a `template <typename T> void read(T&)` that _didn't exist_ in your first code?

Answer (score -2):

I simply put the declarations in front and the rest compiles. I am not a language-lawyer but I believe that gcc is correct here. Some minor modifications to your code to get it compiled without warnings.

```
//Forward declarations needed:
void read(std::string& str);
template <typename T> void read(std::vector<T>& vec);

// mostly your original code
    template <typename T>
T read()
{
    T value;
    read(value); // gcc compile error here
    return value;
}

void read(std::string& )
{
}

    template <typename T>
void read(std::vector<T>& )
{
}

int main() {

    read<std::string>();
    read<std::vector<int>>();
    read<std::vector<float>>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is really obvious solution, but all these functions are in different files and included everywhere in the code. So, I need something generic for all variants of read(SomeClass&).

Comment: so why not put the declarations in a generic header and the rest somewhere else?

Comment: Hey, can the downvoters give some comments? Something wrong? Let me learn also from your knowledge :-) My answer use the same things as from Columbos answer which was answer later but upvoted... Nice :-)