# 'make_error_code' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compiler-errors, mingw

I am using `boost::system::error_code` (of boost 1.62.0) to define custom error codes in C++ like in the following minified example:

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

namespace mynamespace {

enum class MyErrorCodeEnum : int {
    ERROR1 = 1,
    ERROR2 = 2,
};


class MyErrorCategory: public boost::system::error_category
{
public:
    static const MyErrorCategory& instance() {
        static MyErrorCategory category;
        return category;
    }

    // error_category interface
public:
    virtual const char* name() const noexcept {
        return "MyErrorCategory";
    }
    virtual std::string message(int ev) const {
        return "dummy";
    }
};

}

namespace boost {
namespace system {

inline error_code make_error_code(const mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
    return error_code(static_cast<int>(e), mynamespace::MyErrorCategory::instance());
}

inline error_condition make_error_condition(const mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
    return error_condition(static_cast<int>(e), mynamespace::MyErrorCategory::instance());
}

template<>
struct is_error_code_enum<mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum>: public std::true_type {};

}
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    throw boost::system::error_code(mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum::ERROR1);
}
```

This was working just fine using MSVC. However, trying to move to mingw 5.3.0, the following error is reported by the compiler:

```
boost/system/error_code.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::system::error_code::error_code(ErrorCodeEnum, typename boost::enable_if<boost::system::is_error_code_enum<ErrorCodeEnum> >::type*) [with ErrorCodeEnum = mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum; typename boost::enable_if<boost::system::is_error_code_enum<ErrorCodeEnum> >::type = void]':
main.cpp:52:70:   required from here
boost/system/error_code.hpp:329:32: error: 'make_error_code' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
         *this = make_error_code(e);
                                ^
main.cpp:35:19: note: 'boost::system::error_code boost::system::make_error_code(mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum)' declared here, later in the translation unit
 inline error_code make_error_code(const mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
                   ^
```

I can see why it is being reported (the `make_error_code` function is declared after it is being referenced by the constructor of the `error_code` template class), but how am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: Annotation: Real code would not throw the error_code directly but rather a system_error built around it. That does not change the problem, though.

Comment: Put your `make_error_code` declarations before the class `MyErrorCategory`.

Comment: That's not changing anything, unforunately.

Comment: ok, I though that maybe instantiating the class in the static member function requires it to see the methods but ok.

Comment: I posted a fixed version as an answer, haven't used boost for a long time, I'll see why exactly this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully coliru error messages were more explanatory, here is a working version:

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

namespace mynamespace {

enum class MyErrorCodeEnum : int {
    ERROR1 = 1,
    ERROR2 = 2,
};


class MyErrorCategory: public boost::system::error_category
{
public:
    static const MyErrorCategory& instance() {
        static MyErrorCategory category;
        return category;
    }

    // error_category interface
public:
    virtual const char* name() const noexcept {
        return "MyErrorCategory";
    }
    virtual std::string message(int ev) const {
        return "dummy";
    }
};


inline boost::system::error_code make_error_code(const MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
    return boost::system::error_code(static_cast<int>(e), MyErrorCategory::instance());
}

inline boost::system::error_condition make_error_condition(const MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
    return boost::system::error_condition(static_cast<int>(e), MyErrorCategory::instance());
}

}

template<>
struct boost::system::is_error_code_enum<mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum>: public std::true_type {};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    throw boost::system::error_code(mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum::ERROR1);
}
```

The messages generated by clang on coliru where more extensive:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:329:17: error: call to function 'make_error_code' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        *this = make_error_code(e);
                ^
main.cpp:52:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::system::error_code::error_code<mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum>' requested here
    throw boost::system::error_code(mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum::ERROR1);
          ^
main.cpp:35:19: note: 'make_error_code' should be declared prior to the call site or in namespace 'mynamespace'
inline error_code make_error_code(const mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

So yeah, the argument dependent lookup failed, since the namespace did not provide an implementation for `make_error_code` so you either had to move them before the template instantiation or in the same namespace. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379397/template-in-gcc-doesnt-see-a-function-declared-after-it-but-before-instantiati) is a similar question where the answers explain this in more detail.

This works for gcc as well (in the case `is_error_code_enum` is specialized inside `boost::system`):

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

namespace mynamespace {

enum class MyErrorCodeEnum : int {
    ERROR1 = 1,
    ERROR2 = 2,
};

}

namespace boost {
namespace system {

template<>
struct is_error_code_enum<mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum>: public std::true_type {};

}
}

namespace mynamespace {

class MyErrorCategory: public boost::system::error_category
{
public:
    static const MyErrorCategory& instance() {
        static MyErrorCategory category;
        return category;
    }

    // error_category interface
public:
    virtual const char* name() const noexcept {
        return "MyErrorCategory";
    }
    virtual std::string message(int ev) const {
        return "dummy";
    }
};


inline boost::system::error_code make_error_code(const MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
    return boost::system::error_code(static_cast<int>(e), MyErrorCategory::instance());
}

inline boost::system::error_condition make_error_condition(const MyErrorCodeEnum e) {
    return boost::system::error_condition(static_cast<int>(e), MyErrorCategory::instance());
}

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    throw boost::system::error_code(mynamespace::MyErrorCodeEnum::ERROR1);
}
```

Comment: With my compiler settings I get an error complaining about the specialization of `is_error_code_enum` in a different namespace, so I had to move that back to the boost::system namespace. Apart from that, it is working great! Though I don't see why moving the methods to mynamespace is helping, why does the compiler even see those during the `error_code` template evaluation?

Comment: @DevCybran - see the linked question, the second answer explains how the lookup works:) What is the exact error you get regarding the specialization?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
The exact error is: `main.cpp:42:23: error: specialization of 'template<class T> struct boost::system::is_error_code_enum' in different namespace [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @DevCybran - ok I see, clang is happy while gcc is not.

Comment: @DevCybran - I actually made a version that works for gcc as well, see the updated answer:)